# Will sha256 give all possible answers

Tags: hash, sha256, sha

I'm writing this on mobile...

So I was recently thinking about the hash function Sha256 and I though about to what values it mapps.

You can pretty much give Sha256 any value and it would return a 32 character string.

My question is if all 32 character strings will be the result of some value hashed by Sha256.

To clarify my question, is there a 32 character string that will never be the result of a Sha256 hash?

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: oh how should I do then? I'm really bad at fixing this stuff? @AndrewHenle ?

Comment: It is going to be duped in Cryptography https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/304/18298